# icontains does not match any items in the database

Tags: json, django

This is my data:

```
>>> print(MyModel.objects.get(id=1).Fruits) #Fruits is JSONField
>>> print(favorites)
{"Title": ["Fruits"], "Name": ["Banana", "Cherry", "Apple", "Peach"], "Other":["Banana"]}
```

I define a query as follows:

```
>>> query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(Fruits__Name__icontains=x) for x in favorites))
#or: query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(Fruits__icontains={'Name':x}) for x in favorites))
>>> print(query)
(OR: ('Fruits__Name__icontains', 'Apple'), ('Fruits__Name__icontains', 'Banana'))
```

I want it return that item banana or an apple are in `Name`.
When I run this query (postgresql):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

it doesn't match any item in the database.

Comment: Please refer to the docs on querying jsonfields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

Comment: @iri Does not work!

Answer (score 0):

With `MyModel.Fruits` as your `JSONField`, depending on the database used, it might be stored/accessed as string. You could try just accessing `icontains` directly on the JSON string value:

```
Fruits__icontains=x
```

So full query would be:

```
query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(Fruits__icontains=x) for x in favorites))
```

Comment: I updated the question.  If Banana and Apple is not in the 'Name' but are in `Other` query will return that item don't want.

Comment: Could you share your models.py to the question? Just to see what JSONField is being used.

Comment: I used `from django.db import models` and then `Fruits = models.JSONField()` in Postgresql.